# Tawk.to chat not supporting insert file in my web view page

Tags: flutter, webview, laravel-8, flutterwebviewplugin, tawk.to

I'm using Flutter project with Laravel Bakend, I integrate the Tawk.to chat widget in my web-view app, it working and everything is fine just the insert files not working, when clicking on it nothing happens.

```
TitleButton(
                    image: Images.contactUs,
                    title: getTranslated('contact_us', context),
                    navigateTo: WebViewScreen(
                      title: getTranslated('contact_us', context),
                      url: "https://tawk.to/chat/6294c8ee7b967b117991f764/1g5tqalnj",
                    ),
                  ),
```

anyone can help me